# Oracle all date by given range with specific skip days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `from` date and a `to` date. I want select each entry where the day of the month is 05, 15, or 25.
For example if my given date range is from 01 April 2022 to 31 August 2022, my desired output should be

```
05-04-2022
15-04-2022
25-04-2022
.
.
.
15-08-2022
25-08-2022
```

Answer (score 0):

the `extract` function might be what you are looking for ([see here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html)).

A dummy example could look like this

```
with mydata as ( 
select to_date('1-APR-22','DD-MON-YY') thedate, 5 thevalue from dual union all 
select to_date('5-APR-22','DD-MON-YY') thedate, 6 thevalue from dual union all 
select to_date('15-APR-22','DD-MON-YY') thedate, 7 thevalue from dual union all 
select to_date('16-APR-22','DD-MON-YY') thedate, 8 thevalue from dual union all 
select to_date('25-APR-22','DD-MON-YY') thedate, 9 thevalue from dual union all 
select to_date('16-JUN-22','DD-MON-YY') thedate, 10 thevalue from dual union all 
select to_date('25-SEP-22','DD-MON-YY') thedate, 11 thevalue from dual 
)  select * from mydata where extract(day from thedate) in (5,15,25);
```

output:

```
THEDATE     THEVALUE
--------- ----------
05-APR-22          6
15-APR-22          7
25-APR-22          9
25-SEP-22         11
```

so this would appear to do what you are asking for, if I didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: the `to` and `from` date are not respected in here, but one could simply add `and thedate between '1-APR-22' and '31-AUG-22'`

Comment: How much union I will do?

Comment: @IntekhabAlam, everything in the parenthesis from `with` to the parenthesis just before `select * from mydata` is simply to create dummy data to be able to produce output in a self-contained way. You only have to take the query from `select * from mydata` where obviously you need to specify the columns you are interested in, replace the `thedate` column everywhere with the name of the column that contains your `DATETIME` and need to replace `mydata` with the name of your table (which you did not specify in the question, neither the column names, hence I could not adapt the example accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive query to generate the dates. A simple query is the following. It creates all dates in the range and then extracts days 5, 15 and 25. This may be slow on very big date ranges. In that case modify the recursive part to only produce the desired dates in the first place.

```
with dates (dt) as
(
  select :start_date from dual
  union all
  select dt + interval '1' day
  from dates
  where dt < :end_date
)
select *
from dates
where extract(day from dt) in (5, 15, 25)
order by dt;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/8fuWmOUK

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-05', FLOOR((LEVEL - 1)/3))
       + MOD(LEVEL - 1, 3) * 10 AS dt
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15
```

or:

```sql
SELECT m.month + d.day - 1 AS dt
FROM   (
         SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-01', LEVEL - 1) As month
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
       ) m
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT  5 AS day FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 25 FROM DUAL
       ) d
```

or:

```sql
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-05', FLOOR((LEVEL - 1)/3))
       + MOD(LEVEL - 1, 3) * 10 AS dt
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY
       ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-05', FLOOR((LEVEL - 1)/3))
       + MOD(LEVEL - 1, 3) * 10 < DATE '2022-09-01'
```

or:

```sql
SELECT m.month + d.day - 1 AS dt
FROM   (
         SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-01', LEVEL - 1) As month
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-01', LEVEL - 1) < DATE '2022-09-01'
       ) m
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT  5 AS day FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 25 FROM DUAL
       ) d
```

Which all output:

| DT |
| --- |
| 2022-04-05 00:00:00 |
| 2022-04-15 00:00:00 |
| 2022-04-25 00:00:00 |
| 2022-05-05 00:00:00 |
| 2022-05-15 00:00:00 |
| 2022-05-25 00:00:00 |
| 2022-06-05 00:00:00 |
| 2022-06-15 00:00:00 |
| 2022-06-25 00:00:00 |
| 2022-07-05 00:00:00 |
| 2022-07-15 00:00:00 |
| 2022-07-25 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-05 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-15 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-25 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S6bDQDds)

Comment: I want 5,15,25 but your query giving output only 5,15.... And my to_date is dynamic.